# create entity with entity_metadata_wrapper and set Date value

Tags: datetime, entities

I want to create a node entity. This node contain a date field.
So, how can I set the date value ? (using entity_metadata_wrapper)

After several google search and code try, I don't find the solution..
My last try :

```
$date_temp = new DateTime(date('2013-12-01 00:00:00'));
$new_devicew->field_top[0]->field_date->set($date_temp->getTimestamp());
```

But i get this error :

EntityMetadataWrapperException : Unable to set the data property field_date as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->setProperty()

Comment: The error is telling you that `$new_devicew->field_top[0]` is not a wrapped entity object. Make sure `field_top[0]` is returning you the expected entity

Comment: I am not 100% sure if Date is fully compatible with EntityMetadataWrapper.  I need to find some scripts I have to verify this.

Comment: I see, thanks ! 
Its a new entity, so.. the first "field_top" doesn't yet exist

Can you tell me how do I "create" the first "field_top" before I set the field date ?

Comment: MDP => after google search, Date and EntityMetadataWrapper seems ok
But I maybe wrong

Comment: What is field_top?